# How to add optional chaining to JSON object?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, option-type, optional-chaining

I am trying to compare a value within a JSON object with a variable:

```
if (resp.userdetails.name == username) {
// do something
}
```

The problem is that not all `resp` objects have `userdetails`, so I get this error message sometimes:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

I have tried to use `?` to say it might be optional (or not exist):

```
if (resp.userdetails?.name == username)
```

But I get an `Unexpected token` error in that case.

Can someone please tell me how I can update my if statement to say `userdetails` may not always be in the response, but if it is, then check `name` is equal to `username`?

Comment: [You don't seem to know what JSON is](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: `resp?.userdetails?.name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either:

- Use a JS engine [which supports optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility)
- Use a tool like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your JS from a modern version of the language to an older one which doesn't support optional chaining
- Manually test for the object existing before you try to read a property from it

```
if (resp.userdetails && resp.userdetails.name == username)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed [lodash](https://lodash.com/) into your project, then you can use

```
_.get(resp,"userdetails.name")
```

as [documented](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get).

If you haven't installed lodash, then I strongly suggest you install from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) because lodash is the best and the most widely used utility package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Lodash is a popular javascript based library which provides 200+
> functions to facilitate web development. It provides helper functions
> like map, filter, invoke as well as function binding, javascript
> templating, deep equality checks, creating indexes and so on. Lodash
> can be used directly inside a browser and also with Node.js.
>
> Working with objects using JavaScript can be quite challenging,
> specifically if you have lots of manipulation to be done with them.
> Lodash comes with lots of features that eases your work with objects.
>
> Lodash is an open source project and you can easily contribute to the
> library and add features in the form of plugins and make it available
> on GitHub and in Node.js.

**Syntax**

> _.get(object, path, [defaultValue]) Gets the value at path of object. If the resolved value is undefined, the defaultValue is returned in
> its place.
>
> **Arguments**
>
> object (Object) − The object to query.
>
> path (Array|string) − The path of the property to get.
>
> [defaultValue] (*) − The value returned for undefined resolved values.

If you installed [lodash](https://lodash.com/) into your project, then you can use

```
_.get(resp,"userdetails.name")
```

as [documented](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get).

If you haven't installed lodash, then I strongly suggest you install from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) because lodash is the best and the most widely used utility package.

command to install Lodash

```
npm install loadash
```

[image]
Eg:-

```
  var _ = require("lodash");

var data = [
  { userdetails: { name: "d" } },
  {},
  { userdetails: {} },
  { userdetails: { name: "d" } },
];

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var resp = data[i];
  if (_.get(resp, "userdetails.name") == "d") {
    //   if (resp.userdetails && resp.userdetails.name == "d") {    use without loadlash
    console.log("Success");
  } else {
    console.log("failed");
  }
}
```

Here loadash is super complex. But you can use this to avoid runtime errors. Below both expressions get the same result

```
   resp.userdetails && resp.userdetails.name == "d"

                        ===

         _.get(resp, "userdetails.name") == "d"
```